# Wrong dimension on recyclerview grid first row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I am trying to list items on my recycler view using the grid layout manager with two columns.

However, the first row of the grid seems to be having width issues.

[image: first row showing different width than the others]

When I scroll down until the first row is invisible, then scrolled back up, it will fix itself and show the correct width.

[image: correct arrangement of the grid]

My items are retrieved from themoviedb API,

```
adapter.setMovieWrapper(body); // body contains data from the API    
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the layout code for the grid item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:contentDescription="@string/movie_thumbnail_description"/>

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/bg_shade"
        android:id="@+id/movie_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="8dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the adapter code:

```
public class MovieGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieGridItemViewHolder> {
    MovieWrapper movieWrapper;
    private Context context;

    public MovieGridAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MovieWrapper getMovieWrapper() {
        return movieWrapper;
    }

    public void setMovieWrapper(MovieWrapper movieWrapper) {
        this.movieWrapper = movieWrapper;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public MovieGridItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MovieGridItemViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.movie_grid_item, parent, false)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieGridItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = movieWrapper.getResults().get(position);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185");
        uri = uri.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(movie.getPosterPath()).build();

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .into(holder.getThumbnail());

        holder.getTitle().setText(movie.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (movieWrapper != null && movieWrapper.getResults() != null) {
            return movieWrapper.getResults().size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and here is the activity that host the recycler view XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.adityapurwa.popularmovies.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/movie_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone know what is causing this issue and how to resolve it?
Thanks!

Comment: You can share the layout of 1 item in your recyclerView?

Comment: we need more code. SHow the layout of your list item, and code of the adapter. I'm sure there is a problem.

Comment: @RoShanShan - I updated the question to include more codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with my `ConstraintLayout` hosting the `RecyclerView`, I changed it to `FrameLayout` and the issue disappeared. Even though the layout and the `RecyclerView` both have its dimension set to `match_parent`, somehow it fails to detect the dimension.

*Note: Changing the dimension to be absolute (e.g 100dp) also solved the problem, however it makes the layout unresponsive.*

Comment: Although my layout parent is LinearLayout, I still got this error. How to resolve this?

Comment: In my case, I have fixed this by wrapping RecyclerView by a FrameLayout. It's fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have used `FrameLayout` around `Recyclerview` but did not work, I used this work around solution like this, for first 2 items i added dummy items and hidden the views, this worked for me , although this is not a perfect solution